# Bootstrap thumbnails not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I'm working on a meteor app using the Meteor framework. I have added the twbs:bootstrap package to enable quick CSS protoyping. I am currently failing at displaying a set of thumbnails on screen.

Here is the sample source code on JS-Fiddle:

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <li class="span4">
        <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="300x200" />                
            <h4 class="caption">This is my image</h4>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/M3fpA/46/

As you can see, it works as expected. Now I have copied this exact piece of source code over to my project just for demonstration purposes. It looks like this on my frontend:

[Screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/ukvtr8uz1/)
(Sorry, apparently I am not allowed to post pictures directly here to help you guys ...)

Its obviously quite messed up, but I can't seem to understand why. Here is the source of the template used for this page:

```
<template name="inventory">
  <h1>Inventory</h1>
  <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span4">
          <a class="thumbnail" href="#">
              <img src="http://placehold.it/300x200" alt="300x200" />
              <h4 class="caption">This is my image</h4>
          </a>
      </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Bootstrap 2.3.2 markup in your example and jsfiddle, however when adding `twbs:bootstrap`, it will load the latest Bootstrap at version 3.3.5, hence the problem.

You should not use such an old version of Bootstrap since version 3 has been around for almost 2 years now, please refer to [current Bootstrap thumbnails documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#thumbnails).